# How to use Guice Dependency Injection to get object in class that doesn't have main method?

Tags: java, guice

I have a class that does not have the main method. This class is also used by code that is not in my control. This class has a method that takes a String as a parameter, and then based on the value of that String it needs to create different objects. How can I use Guice to create these objects? I think the answer has something to do with Providers, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Here is the class in question, which doesn't use DI to make the objects:

```
public class ActionHandler {

    public void doSomething(String message) throws Exception {

        ActionObject actionObj = null;

        if (message.equals("dog")) {
            // ActionObjectDog implements ActionObject
            actionObj = new ActionObjectDog(); 
        }
        else if (message.equals("cat")) {
            // ActionObjectCat implements ActionObject
            actionObj = new ActionObjectCat(); 
        }
        else {
            throw new Exception("Action " + message + " not implemented.");
        }

        actionObj.run();
    }
}
```

I was trying to inject a Provider, but I got stuck because I couldn't figure out how to make the Provider get() method return a specific implementation of ActionObject.

```
@Inject private Provider<ActionObject> actionObjectProvider;
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Provider` won't work for your situation because, as you have discovered, `get()` doesn't take any parameters.

One option is to use a `MapBinder`:

```
class Module extends AbstractModule {
  @Override protected void configure() {
    MapBinder.newMapBinder(binder(), String.class, ActionObject.class)
        .addBinding("dog").to(ActionObjectDog.class);
    MapBinder.newMapBinder(binder(), String.class, ActionObject.class)
        .addBinding("cat").to(ActionObjectCat.class);
  }
}

class ActionHandler {
  private final Map<String, ActionObject> mappings;
  @Inject ActionHandler(Map<String, ActionObject> mappings) {
    this.mappings = mappings;
  }

  public void doSomething(String message) {
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(mappings.get(message), "No action for '" + message + "'")
        .run();
  }
}
```

It's not leveraging any awesome Guiciness, but it moves the `ActionObject` selection logic out of `ActionHandler`, which is what it sounds like you're trying to do.  The injected map is just a `Collections.UnmodifiableMap`, so the same instance will be returned with each call to `mappings.get(...)`, which means your `ActionObject` implementations would need to be threadsafe.

Also, I'm confused by the specific attention being paid to the lack of a `main` method.  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the problem, but you can create a Guice `Injector` from anywhere you'd like.  If the above solution doesn't work for you, can you expand on that restriction?

Comment: The reason I mentioned the lack of a main method is because I read that it is best to create your injector early in the program, and all examples have the injector being made in the main() method.

Comment: OK.  That is all correct, but it's not hard to work around if your hands are tied.  So is this answer missing something?  I noticed it hasn't been accepted, so please let me know if the solution needs to be changed or improved.

Comment: If the ActionHandler object is created in code that is not in my control, does that mean Guice can't be used here?

Comment: Then I'm confused what you're trying to do if `ActionHandler` is created in code not in your control and used by code not in your control.  What is it that you're hoping Guice can help you out with?

Comment: I heard that Guice can improve code testability and readability. Your answer and comments has helped me understand that Guice wont help me in my particular situation.

Comment: It may not work here, but I would recommend trying to make the DI pattern work where you can.  It's very valuable for testing.  <http://www.drdobbs.com/tools/dependency-injection-testable-objects/185300375> seems to do a good job showing how to make your classes more testable with DI.  I'd say 95% of the reason my class constructors always depend on interfaces is so I can easily create mock objects, either by hand or with Mockito, that implement those interfaces but return canned responses.  That way I can focus on testing just the class under test.